# concatenate the cell value with result of If formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the formula below which checks cell C6 and if C6="Yes", formula will return "X".

```
IF(C6="Yes","X","")
```

I now want this formula to concatenate the value of Cell C5 to string "X" only when the C6="Yes". How can I formulate this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addendum to Scott's answer, depending on your purpose you can also use `CONCAT` or `TEXTJOIN`. For instance:

```
=IF(C6="Yes",CONCAT("X",C5),"")
```

...or...

```
=IF(C6="Yes",TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,"X",C5),"")
```

If C5 is "example", these would result in "Xexample" and "X example", respectively. As Plutian mentioned, this is particularly useful if you're going to have more entries. `TEXTJOIN` is particularly useful if you're trying to make a sentence or concatenate an address separated by commas. It can also ignore blank cells, which can be handy.

Answer (score 3):

Like this, using `&` to concatenate:

```
IF(C6="Yes","X"&C5,"")
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `Concatenate(` for larger amounts of entries. It's less quick and elegant, but sometimes easier to make sense off and better to use if additional formulas are involved.